# Groups of units of cyclic groups of order $2^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

In Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra (2nd ed.), Corollary 20(2) states the following:

> $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the direct product of a cyclic group of order 2 and a cyclic group of order $2^{n-2}$, for all $n\geq2$.

For the proof, it says "it directly follows from Exercises 22 and 23 of Section 2.3." From these exercises, I learned that $5$ is an element of order $2^{n-2}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ for $n\geq2$, and that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is not cyclic for $n\geq3$.
But I don't see how these imply that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is a product of two cyclic groups of order 2 and $2^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$|(\Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z})^\times| = 2^{n-1}$ and index 2 subgroups are normal...

Comment: Does an index 2 (normal) subgroup necessarily split the group into a direct product? I don't think so... consider a semidirect product $G\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, for example...

Comment: @ashpool :  You only ask for "a product".